# invalid_grant for password grant_type Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to create an access_token for my API, but I have problem that show this message:

```
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": "Client authentication failed",
"message": "Client authentication failed"
```

This my request data:

```
{
  "username":"neal.jacobi@example.org",
  "password":"test1234",
  "grant_type":"password",
  "client_id": "2",
  "client_secret":"jScq3DMMeZctypnYb7f1ClEHyzybwTK1Yisqo09E"
}
```

This my oauth_clients table:

[image: oauth_clients_table]

Comment: Do you mean the `Request data` by saying `header` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to add `scope` in your request data.

```
{
  "username":"neal.jacobi@example.org",
  "password":"test1234",
  "grant_type":"password",
  "client_id": "2",
  "client_secret":"jScq3DMMeZctypnYb7f1ClEHyzybwTK1Yisqo09E",
  "scope" => ""
}
```

If you have any problems, tell me.

Comment: when I add scope show unsupported_grant_type

Comment: with "scope" : "*" work

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the following in request body.

```
{
  "username":"neal.jacobi@example.org",
  "password":"test1234",
  "grant_type":"password",
  "client_id": "2",
  "client_secret":"jScq3DMMeZctypnYb7f1ClEHyzybwTK1Yisqo09E"
}
```

The client credentials are being validated from the request body in the following method.

```
// League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\AbstractGrant 
// line 253 
protected function getClientCredentials(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        [$basicAuthUser, $basicAuthPassword] = $this->getBasicAuthCredentials($request);

        $clientId = $this->getRequestParameter('client_id', $request, $basicAuthUser); // It is fetching from request body

        if (\is_null($clientId)) {
            throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('client_id');
        }

        $clientSecret = $this->getRequestParameter('client_secret', $request, $basicAuthPassword);

        if ($clientSecret !== null && !\is_string($clientSecret)) {
            throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('client_secret');
        }

        return [$clientId, $clientSecret];
    }
```